# DownloadManager в Clean Architecture

Tags: android, архитектура

Как организовать работу с [`android.app.DownloadManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) в рамках Clean Architecture?

Предположительно, работа с ним должна идти на уровне реализации Data-слоя, но этому препятствует несколько вещей:

1. Доступ к `DownloadManager` осуществляется через вызов `Context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE)`. У этого метода есть пометка, которая ставит под сомнение использование единственного экземпляра `DownloadManager` для разных экранов:

> System services obtained via this API may be closely associated with the Context in which they are obtained from. In general, do not share the service objects between various different contexts (Activities, Applications, Services, Providers, etc.)

2. Обработка результатов работы `DownloadManager` делается с помощью `BroadcastReceiver`. Хотелось бы использовать их только на тех экранах, на которых идёт работа с загрузкой файлов, но при этом сделать для них обёртку Data-уровня проще, если они объявлены как глобальные, в манифесте.
3. Непонятно, что лучше передавать в качестве результата работы `DownloadManager`. `File`, `Uri`, какую-то обёртку DownloadResult, которая будет содержать статус загрузки, или что-то ещё?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша идея работать с `DownloadManager` на урове `data-layer` верна. Его необходимо рассматривать как источника данных `(Retrofit)`. Его основная задача загрузить файл, и уведомлять о статусе загрузки файла.

1. Репозиторий создаётся создаётся с использованием `ApplicationContext`. Репозиторий умеет работать с `DownloadManager` и для этого ему нужен будет только `Context`. И по необходимости `Context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE)` будет нам возвращать ссылку. Другие слои вообще не будут знать о существовании `DownloadManager`, а следовательно не будет проблемы общего доступа.
2. `BroadcastReceiver` необходимо зарегистрировать в манифесте. Т.о задача `BroadcastReceiver` состоит только в том, чтобы получать статус текущей загрузки. Сам статус он не будет обрабатывать, а будет передавать его `Service`, который будет отвечать за обработку ответа от `DownloadManager`. У этой службы будет список слушателей, которые подписаны на статус загрузки.
3. Необходимо возвращать объект, который описывает загрузку : статус, прогресс, название файла или путь. Этот объект можно расширять по необходимости.